# Swapping the Position and Z-Index of 2 divs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm currently trying to swap the placement of two divs along with the z-index. 
So far this is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
        $('.herotrend').click(function()
        {
                $(this).animate({
                        top: $('.herotrend:eq(1)').css('top'),
                        left: $('.herotrend:eq(1)').css('left'),
                        z: $('.herotrend:eq(1)').css('zIndex')
                }, 100);

                $('#music').animate({
                        top: $('.herotrend:eq(0)').css('top'),
                        left: $('.herotrend:eq(0)').css('left'),
                        z: $('.herotrend:eq(0)').css('zIndex')
                }, 100);
        });
});
```

This has managed to successfully swap the positions of the elements, but I'm still having trouble getting the z-index to swap as well.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: @ahren you should add that as an actual answer.

Comment: @mmmshuddup - fair point, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
zIndex: $('.herotrend:eq(1)').css('zIndex')
```

not

```
z: $('.herotrend:eq(1)').css('zIndex')
```

Comment: +1 now if only @Zain would _accept_ your answer, this could all be over :P